# Generate docfx site using existing docfx.json

Tags: c#, documentation-generation, docfx

So I have a `docfx.json` which is configured correctly and targets the correct directories. What I'm wondering is how can I generate site using that `docfx.json` from scratch.

E.g. I have a blank directory with just the `docfx.json` in it and want to generate all the site and documentation using that `docfx.json`.

Like using the `docfx init` command but instead of generating a blank site I generate the site using the existing `docfx.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually do the setup yourself. See more info on how to do that [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5259812/Use-DocFx-to-Generate-a-Documentation-Web-Site-and)